# How can I return an entire query to the browser using Python, Flask and MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

At present I am returning a record back to the browser by what I would call manually i.e. "field : s['fieldresult']".  Is there a way to return the whole document result straight back to the browser without manually doing each field like the above?

I've read the data is BSON but I've tried various convert code and none of it has worked.

```
@app.route('/companyTest/', methods=['GET'])
def companyTest():
    company = mongo.db.companies
    s = company.find_one({'company_number' : '124'})
    if s:
        output = {'company_name' : s['company_name'], 'company_status' : s['company_status']}

    else:
        output = "No such name"
    return jsonify({'result' : output})
```

Comment: What is wrong with `{ "result": s }`? It's exactly the same is it not? Or do you just want to remove the `_id`?

Comment: You can just do a `s.pop('_id')` inside try except for safe side, and do a `return jsonify(result=result)` at the end.

Comment: what doesnt work?  What error are you getting?

Comment: I get no error with the code above, it's adding each line from the document that I want to overcome.